# Groovy xml get node text

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm reading a html page with XmlParser in groovy.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
tr?.td?.each{
 println it
}
```

it prints the following:

```
td[attributes={colspan=9, width=129}; value=[p[attributes={}; value=[O-???????????]]]]
```

The page contains unicode text, but if I print:

```
it.text()
```

it prints nothing. I want to get *what ever may be the content with in* .

Answer (score 0):

I can't get the behaviour you describe.  Given

```
def xml = '''<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Woo</td>
                <td>Yay</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Woo</td>
                <td>Yay</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>'''

import groovy.xml.*

new XmlParser().parseText( xml ).body.table.tr.td.each {
    println it.text()
}
```

prints

```
Woo
Yay
Woo
Yay
```

Comment: if td contains text like `<td><img /><p></p>Woo</td>` how to get `<img /><p></p>Woo`?

Comment: Thats harder :-(  You can do: `new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml ).body.table.tr.td.each { element ->
    println new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bindNode( element )
}` to get `<td><img></img><p></p>Woo</td>`... Not sure how to get rid of the enclosing `<td>` though

Answer (score 0):

Do theis it.get(0).text()

Reason is what you get 
td[attributes={colspan=9, width=129}; value=[p[attributes={}; value=[O-???????????]]]]

is NodeList which is a subclass of arraylist. 
But .text() is the method of Node. 
So you need to get the Node obj from NodeList then do .text()